# ng-repeat not looping through subobject

Tags: angularjs, loops, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have a variable I instantiate as

```
$scope.invites = { 'userID': null, 'users': [], 'errorMsg': null, 'pending': [] };
```

In an API request, I set `$scope.invites.pending` to an array of objects, for example:

```
[{ userID: 1, username: 'RhoVisions'}]
```

When I use ng-repeat in an li

```
<li ng-repeat="invite in invites.pending | orderBy: 'username'">
```

I get nothing. Inspecting shows nothing ever gets rendered. If I change the variable from `$scope.invites.pending` to `$scope.invitesPending`, it works just fine, and I can't seem to figure out the issue.

At first, I thought maybe its because of the way data comes in, so I tried looping through the returned data and pushing it to `$scope.invites.pending`, with on luck. I also tried adding a `track by $index` at the behest of a friend, which also didn't work.

I tried creating a plnkr, but it works fine with plnkr. I have to imagine it has something to do with my code, or how data comes in from an API, but I have no idea what to do. I can change it to basic variable, but for the sake of organization and learning, I'd love to figure out what's going on.

Because it requires APIs, I can't setup a working plnkr, but I've put the relevant output HTML as well as the full JS file that runs the page. Only the stuff pertinent to invites is relevant as far as I know.

http://plnkr.co/edit/3lh2MT1JHzOeN0baR3BO

Comment: Can you show us full code? If it works on plnkr, there's no way to debug with what you've given us.

Answer (score 0):

1. I think your json is invalid - `userId`, `users`, `errorMsg` and `pending` should not be wrapped in single quotes - they should be wrapped in double quotes. So should the username.
2. Please try hardcoding your array of objects to see if the ng-repeat works. e.g.

   `$scope.invites = { 
       userID: null, 
       users: [], 
       errorMsg: null, 
       pending: [
           { userID: 1, username: "RhoVisions"},
           { userID: 2, username: "AhotherUser"}
       ]
   };`
3. If still not working, then check that your $http promise has resolved? e.g. in the `.then(function() { alert('hello') })` to make sure that it has successfully resolved.
4. Update your question with the actual payload being returned from your API.
5. Can you show us your full code? As it's a bit difficult to debug with the amount of info you have provided us. Maybe a link to your Plnkr?

I have created a plnkr for you showing that it works... http://plnkr.co/edit/9RvTgJbMZGuOFiosrMfT?p=preview

Comment: So... 1) I'm pretty sure the order by is fine, though I'll try the fix; I've done it in similar ways in the past, to the best of my knowledge. 2) I have tried hard coding it, no success. 3) I know the HTTP request works, as all the other data it returns displays fine; it's just this one piece that doesn't work. And as mentioned, when used as a variable straight off scope, it works fine. I'll setup a plnkr with my full code (won't be able to make it functional, as it requires API returns).

Comment: I definitely know it CAN work, and I've created a plnkr that shows it works myself, but for some reason, in my code, it doesn't. I've added a link to a plnkr with my code.

Comment: As far as I know, single or double quotes shouldn't matter for validiating, plus the JSON validates in 3 different online validation sites. Regardless, I found my issue.

Answer (score 0):

I was an idiot and forgot that I added a new directive into the invites section, and apparently its not working as its supposed to. Instead of just writing data to a pass variable (invites.user), its overwriting the entire variable.